# Convert datetime to string without default time value

Tags: c#, datetime, visual-studio-2012, datetimepicker

When I convert selected date of a DateTimePicker to a string it gives value like "01/03/2013 12:00:00 AM". How I can drop the time value and select only "01/03/2013" part?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

try this [ToShortDateString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.toshortdatestring.aspx):

```
var datestring = datePicker.Value.ToShortDateString();
```

It will

> Converts the value of the current DateTime object to its equivalent
>   short date string representation.
>
> The string returned by the ToShortDateString method is
>   culture-sensitive. It reflects the pattern defined by the current
>   culture's DateTimeFormatInfo object. For example, for the en-US
>   culture, the standard short date pattern is "M/d/yyyy"; for the de-DE
>   culture, it is "dd.MM.yyyy"; for the ja-JP culture, it is "yyyy/M/d".
>   The specific format string on a particular computer can also be
>   customized so that it differs from the standard short date format
>   string.

if you want excactly `dd/MM/yyyy` format use custom ToString() like:

```
var datestring = datePicker.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: Note that your last approach could fail if the current culture doesn't use `/` as date separator but he wants to enforce it. Use `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` as second parameter in `ToString` then. Btw, `ToShortdateString` is the same as `ToString("d")`. See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx#ShortDate

Answer (score 1):

use it

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var day = value.Date; // a DateTime that will just be whole days
var time = value.TimeOfDay; // a TimeSpan that is the duration into the day
```

it will work for you